# Why is the scope in my angularJS app empty?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm new to angular and am trying to tweek the tutorial to my app.  I'm trying to add routes to my app and it doesn't seem to be reading my templates or reading the controller correctly. I installed the angularJS extension for Chrome (pretty awesome by the way) and it shows my scope as empty, no models.
Here's my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="bioSatApp">
<head>
    <title>Map Test</title>
    <script src="../lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="../resources/app.js"></script>
    <script src="../resources/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my app module (app.js):

```
var bioSatApp = angular.module('bioSatApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'biosatAppControllers'
]);

bioSatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/maptypes', {
                templateURL: 'partials/mapType-list.html',
                controller: 'MapListCtrl'
            }).
            when('/maptypes/:type', {
                templateURL: 'partials/mapType-detail.html',
                controller: 'MapTypeCtrl'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/maptypes'
            });
    }]);
```

Here's my controllers module (controllers.js):

```
var biosatAppControllers = angular.module('biosatAppControllers', []);

biosatAppControllers.controller('MapListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 
    function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('../resources/maptypes.json').success(function (data) {
            $scope.mapTypes = data;

        });
}]);
biosatAppControllers.controller('MapTypeCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
    function ($scope, $routeParams) {
        $scope.type = $routeParams.type
    }]);
```

Here's mapType-list.html:

```
<select onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option ng-repeat="map in mapTypes" value="#/maptypes/{{map.type}}">
        {{map.caption}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Here's mapType-detail.html:

```
<div>
    {{type}}
    <div id="legendContainer" style="width: 300px; height: 800px; overflow-y: auto; float: left;">Legend Div</div>
    <div id="mapDiv" style="height:800px;">Map Div</div>
</div>
```

The maptypes.json is valid json and it loaded successfully before I tried to ngRoute.

When I run the code it successfully navigates the app to /maptypes (the otherwise statement in $routeProvider).  But it doesn't bring up the mapType-list html, which should be a simple drop down list.  I get no errors in my console or anywhere else that says something isn't loading correctly or something's not found.  Also, when I run it the ng-view div element:

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

get's replaced with a comment:

```
<!-- ngView: -->
```

I'm sure it's something very simple that I'm missing or got wrong, but I've looked through the code over and over and I can't look at it anymore.

Comment: Instead of that pretty awesome Chrome extension. Try this: inspect the element with dev tools, in console type: `angular.element($0).scope()` and see what it outputs.

Comment: hah, rookie mistake.  The when method uses templateUrl not templateURL.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your app config to

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        //Your routing here...
```

Also add `<base href="/">` to head of your HTML file.

Comment: Same result, just has a shortened url.

Answer (score 0):

Here the example I did using the same code

sample1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="bioSatApp">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-view></div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app1.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*With **app1.js** I did different of you because I deleted 2 lines from here:*

```
var bioSatApp = angular.module('bioSatApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'biosatAppControllers'
]);
```

- 'ngRoute'
- 'biosatAppControllers'

and also I changed **templateURL** for **templateUrl**

This is the result without the 2 lines:

```
var bioSatApp = angular.module('bioSatApp', []);

bioSatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/maptypes', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/mapType-list.html'
            }).
            when('/maptypes/:type', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/mapType-detail.html',
                controller: 'MapTypeCtrl'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/maptypes'
            });
    }]);
```

All the others files are the same